# Using an array to create objects in a class

Tags: java, arrays, object

I changed from a `Event eventStuff` 1, 2, and 3 `= new Event;` to the below format. I have changed nothing in the Event class, so I don't think that is the issue. My purpose here is to simplify code by using an array. This is my first broach into arrays, and I'm not sure what is going wrong. I keep getting a "NullPointerException" after the motto is called (i.e. eventStuff[x]). It seems to me that during the first run, x = 0, the second, x = 1, and the third, x = 2. What am I doing wrong?

```
package chapter.pkg8;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class EventDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        callMotto();
        Event[] eventStuff = new Event[3];
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; ++x){
            eventStuff[x].setEventCodeString();
            eventStuff[x].setGuests();
            eventStuff[x].setContactNumber();
            eventStuff[x].setEventStr();
        }
    }

    public static void callMotto(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
        "*******************************************************\n"
        +   "* Carly's Makes The Food That Makes The Party! *\n"
        +   "*******************************************************");
    }

}
```

Comment: Your arrays are full of nulls.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm not well versed in the language. Could you be more specific, for my sake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Event[] eventStuff = new Event[3];
```

you should initialize the value first:

```
eventStuff[0]=new event();
eventStuff[1]=new event();
eventStuff[2]=new event();
```

---

without initializing values of `eventStuff`, the default values will be `[null, null, null]`

therefore, calling

```
eventStuff[x].setEventCodeString();
eventStuff[x].setGuests();
eventStuff[x].setContactNumber();
eventStuff[x].setEventStr();
```

will give you `NullPointerException`

Comment: Of course, your suggestion worked flawlessly. Thank you so very much for the support!

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>(3);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        Event evt = new Event();
        events.setXXX(***);
        events.setXXX(***);
        events.setXXX(***);
        events[i] = evt;
    }
```

you just allocate the array, but not the objects will be stored in the array